# Flutter could not find the correct Provider<Bloc> after navigating to different route

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider, flutter-bloc

I'm using bloc to handle the state of a signup form. But I get the error:
`Error: Could not find the correct Provider<CreateDidBloc> above this BlocBuilder<CreateDidBloc, CreateDidState> Widget`.
As you can see in the error I do use the bloc `CreateDidBloc` and the state `CreateDidState` and get them through a BlocBuilder.
The BlocBuilder is positioned in my "signup" page, which in my case is called `Creation`. The error occurs when I'm navigating from my introduction page to the creation page.
Below is an extract of my `MaterialApp` in which I wrap the creation page with a `RepositoryProvider` and `BlocProvider` so that the creation page has access to the Bloc and repository. But for some reason does the `creation` page not find the BlocProvider for the `CreateDidBloc` after navigating to the creation page.

```
initialRoute: "/introduction",
routes: {
  "/introduction": (context) => Introduction(),
  "/create": (context) => RepositoryProvider(
        create: (context) => CreateDidRepository(),
        child: BlocProvider(
          create: (BuildContext context) => CreateDidBloc(
            repo: context.read<CreateDidRepository>(),
          ),
          child: Creation(),
        ),
      ),
},
```

This is how I navigate to the `Creation` screen:

```
Navigator.push(context,
    PageTransition(type: PageTransitionType.fade, child: Creation()));
```

Creation (signup) page:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
          body: Column(
    children: [
      Expanded(
        child: PageView(
          physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          controller: _pageController,
          onPageChanged: (index) {
            setState(() => currentStep = index);
          },
          children: [
            Step1(),
            Step2(),
            Step3(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: [
          BlocBuilder<CreateDidBloc, CreateDidState>(
            builder: (context, state) {
              return ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    next();
                  },
                  child: Text(L.of(context).next));
            },
          ),
          BlocBuilder<CreateDidBloc, CreateDidState>(
            builder: (context, state) {
              return OutlinedButton(
                  onPressed:
                      state.formStatus is FormSubmitting ? null : cancel,
                  child: Text(L.of(context).back));
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
      const SizedBox(
        height: 16,
      )
    ],
  )));
}
```

This is the stack trace:

```
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#0      Provider._inheritedElementOf
#1      Provider.of
#2      ReadContext.read
#3      _BlocBuilderBaseState.initState
#4      StatefulElement._firstBuild
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I found the reason for why my BlocBuilder couldn't find the `CreateDidBloc` after navigating. That error occurs because navigating in Flutter pushes your page right below the MaterialApp in the widget tree. That means that my newly navigated Page is above the BlocProvider which is specified in the widget tree below the MaterialApp.
To fix this I just wrapped my MaterialApp with a MultiBlocProvider and the RepositoryProvider so that the Bloc is provided globally no matter in what route I am.
This is the important extract in which I can define the blocs globally:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RepositoryProvider(
        create: (context) => CreateDidRepository(),
        child: MultiBlocProvider(
            providers: [
              BlocProvider<LanguageBloc>(
                  create: (context) =>
                      LanguageBloc(LanguagePreference.getLanguage())),
              BlocProvider<CreateDidBloc>(
                  create: (context) =>
                      CreateDidBloc(repo: context.read<CreateDidRepository>()))
            ],
            child: BlocBuilder<LanguageBloc, LanguageState>(
              builder: (context, state) {
                return MaterialApp(...)
```

Comment: I feel like this is supposed to be in a documentation somewhere.. Anyways thanks for the HUGE help!!!

Comment: It's bad practice to create global providers in case they should not be accessible  for the whole app features. Your sign-up bloc should be provided only to the sign-up flow.

Comment: What if I don't want to provide a bloc to the whole app but still need it on multiple screens?

Significantly when this bloc depends on future data from another bloc (It adds complications)

Comment: I am wondering the same... I cannot believe this is not covered in the documentation or at least it's not that clear